# I am having a problem with opening youtube with the click of a button

Tags: android-studio, buttonclick

Ok so I want my app to open youtube when a button is clicked. For some reason it does not work!

this is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btn_subscribe = findViewById<Button>(R.id.sub_button)
        btn_subscribe.setOnClickListener{
            btn_subscribe.text = "Subscribed"
            val webIntent: Intent = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com").let { webpage ->
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm Java Developer so I cannot code with Kotlin but I'll show you how to open youtube from your app.
Use this method in your button `ClickListner`

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/c/AndroidDevelopers")));
```

Your new code looks like below

```
btn_subscribe.setOnClickListener{
            btn_subscribe.text = "Subscribed"
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/c/AndroidDevelopers")));
            }
        }
```

Make sure to change `JAVA` to `Kotlin` in my code. If you any problem is causing, Let me know

Comment: How do I convert java code to kotlin?